# Comparar dos strings con restricciones con MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Tengo que comparar dos strings de n y m líneas respectivamente con una restricción, los últimos 4 dígitos de esta. Los mensajes son de la siguiente forma:

```
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,H3F974P4hTEH400000000000000,2*420033
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13EcsW7P00P:07bGc9Wh0?w22<0l,0*770033
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13EmCs70000:0;DGc<MJ`3340D14,0*440034
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13EsReP00009vQ`Gbj65gPi006p0,0*6C0034
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,15AMJH00000:1i:Ga0s00Ai406p0,0*780034
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13F9RTPP00P9rKlGasQf4?w42L1D,0*430034
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13Efqs800109q62Gb0tHhq?82@Dp,0*010035
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13E`977P00P:064Gc8Bkwww62@Dr,0*030035
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,H3F974TU00000000000000189230,0*210036
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13cq;9000GP9s`0Gb390e0c28@E:,0*160036
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,4028j;1vDfG0S09cFjGdh5A000S:,0*180036
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,D028j;1Mdffp,0*610036
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13EpM3PP0009nVdGb9MM??w80<1K,0*1F0036
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13Esmv000009qWBGb=CdHAU:06p0,0*7B0036
!AIVDM,2,1,9,A,53:F8V82=dFA3=IcV20EE8u0F222222222222216PA<=N4f5NLiDhPk`8888,0*070037
!AIVDM,2,2,9,A,88888888880,2*2D0037
```

Los últimos 4 dígitos nos dan el tiempo. Mi restricción es que los mensajes de un string se tienen que comparar con los otros del string que estén dentro del rango que pongamos, en este caso es un minuto menos i un minuto más.
Ejemplo:

```
!AIVDM,2,2,9,A,88888888880,2*2D**0037**
```

este mensaje acaba en `0037` y se tendrá que comparar con todos los mensajes del otro script que vayan, en este caso del `0000` al `0137`. El mínimo es `0000` y el máximo es el `5959`.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!